# Product info tabs click to scroll

Tags: magento2, product

I'm using magento 2.

Can you help me to edit Product info tabs content show one page and click the tab will scroll, same url below?

https://marketplace.magento.com/swissup-easytabs.html#product.info.description

Comment: do you have this module installed and have button in product info section somewhere so it will scroll down to tab sections ? that is what you want.. could you share your screen shot to better explain the issue

Comment: No, unrelated to this module. I mean when I click the tab: Overview
Release Notes - Support - Q & A - Reviews. It will scroll down to tab content.